Pandas .replace() with multiple many to one mappings
I have a pandas column with some strings in.  I want to group up the strings that are similar, and replace with their category.  In my real example, I have 6 different strings, and I wanted to replace then with 3 different strings for their categories.
I found this answer for how to map many values to 1 using in the replace() function, so I tried expanding some of the answers to do a many to 1 mapping for multiple groups, however not all of my values were correctly changed and I'm not sure why.
As an example:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['foo', 'foo too', 'bar', 'BAR', 'bar ii']})
    col1
0   foo
1   foo too
2   bar
3   BAR
4   bar ii

From one of the answers, it looked like you could use '|' to separate different key options if you used regex, so I did this like below:
df1['col1'].replace({'foo|foo too' : 'Foo',
                     'bar|BAR|bar ii' : 'Bar'}, regex=True)

Which converted most of my strings, but not all:
    col1
0   Foo
1   Foo too
2   Bar
3   Bar
4   Bar ii

From this example, I would guess something to do with the spaces? although in my actual example some of my strings with spaces did get correctly replaced, so I'm not sure.  Any help with why this doesn't work/how I could achieve what I'm after would be appreciated

You have to craft your regex to ensure that a substring of another pattern doesn't appear before a longer string.
This means that foo|foo too will match foo before foo to. Therefore, foo to|foo should be used.
df1['col1'].replace({'foo too|foo' : 'Foo',
                     'bar ii|BAR|bar' : 'Bar'}, regex=True)

Output:
0    Foo
1    Foo
2    Bar
3    Bar
4    Bar
Name: col1, dtype: object

A generic way to ensure that longer words always appear first would be to sort the strings:
import re

motifs = {'Foo': ['foo', 'foo too'],
          'Bar': ['bar', 'BAR', 'bar ii'],
         }

dic = {'|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -len(x)))) : k
       for k, lst in motifs.items()}

df1['col1'].replace(dic, regex=True)

Note that this only works with simple strings, not necessarily more complex regex for which a shorter regex can match a more generic string than a longer one.
Additionally, if you want to replace the full string if a substring is found, then another option would be:
df1['col1'].replace({'.*(foo|foo too).*' : 'Foo',
                     '.*(bar|BAR|bar ii).*' : 'Bar'}, regex=True)

Be aware that this would replace all patterns that contain foo or bar even if there are other parts.
